# GetScript(url+'three.js); не выполняет загруженную библиотеку

Tags: jquery, ajax, three.js, javascript

Загрузка завершается со статусом 200, в логах все хорошо.

Но по факту, сама библиотека не выполнилась, и последующие скрипты, использующие ее, тоже.
Если написать в первой строке библиотека что-то типа alert или console.log, то библиотека выполняется. C чем может быть связан косяк?